# Put guest posts on site with other languages

Tags: seo, backlinks

My website is in a persian language. Can writing "guest posts" on english or russian language websites benefit the SEO for my own website?

Comment: Guest posts generally hurt SEO these days.   They are often not high quality.   They may be duplicated elsewhere.   They are often created for the purpose of including links which Google views as a form of paid links.   Even without the language mismatch, guest posts may not be a good idea for SEO.

Comment: Web sites that are focused do well. If you start reaching into other areas almost haphazardly, then your web site will fail. Focus on topics and focus on the languages of your target audience. Commit to a plan and execute fully with intention. A few posts here and there will NOT help at all. It WILL hurt. Do not make posts on other sites for backlinks. Horrible idea!

Comment: My web site is persian (فارسی). If I writing a quality guest post about car on yahoo news. Is it terrible?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on whether you have another posts in these languages. If it is the single post in foreign language - it would rather harm, than bring benefits.

Comment: My website posts is only persian.

Comment: Than don't do it. Or do it only, if you will get more content in this another language - than you establish a second language site version.

Answer (score -1):

I think that overall, content is king. And if you can add great content to your website than this is a plus. If the guest post is off topic or poorer content than the rest of your site then this could dilute your niche with Google.

For instance, if your site is about cars, and you publish a post about icecream in a different language, Google could find this somewhat suspect.

However, it's very common for companies to start stretching out into foreign markets. And the way that is done is by slowly beginning to add more and more content in that language to their website. And so I would consider it a wise marketing move to add alternate language content to your website if it's in your niche. This is especially the case if you intend to continue branching out into that language.

Comment: I do not want to add another language to my website. My website language is farsi ( Persian ). Can I writing a post on an English-language site. for example: our site is about cars, and we publish a post about benz in a different language for back link. A quality post

Comment: for example: our site is about cars, and we publish a guest post about benz in a other different website language for back link. A quality post

Comment: Yes that's fine. You can publish English articles on other sites. Though Google will see the language difference of your site and therefore will likely not send you English speaking traffic to your Farsi page. But the English site backlinks should drive more Farsi speaking searchers to your site.

Comment: This last comment is my answer. But there is no green tick. what should I do?